# Resizing and reclaiming free space on Tablespaces

Tags: oracle-11g

I would like to reclaim some free space from our tablespaces. I can see that `UNDOTBS1` and `USERS` for example have 30GB and 10GB free.

these are the tablespaces:

```
| tablespace    | used mb   | free mb   | total mb  | pct. free     |
|------------   |---------  |---------  |---------- |-----------    |
| SYSAUX        | 3268      | 152       | 3420      | 4             |
| UNDOTBS1      | 991       | 31777     | 32768     | 97            |
| USERS         | 186866    | 10766     | 197632    | 5             |
| SYSTEM        | 3360      | 30        | 3390      | 1             |
| INDEXES       | 32920     | 2920      | 35840     | 8             |
```

I could see on ASKTOM, and other questions that I need to:

```
PURGE TABLESPACE MyTs
aLTER TABLESPACE MyTs COALESCE
```

and then:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'Datafile_here' RESIZE 3g
```

But I would like to know how much can I reclaim. when i try to redize `UNDOTBS1` for example, it says I cannot trim space that is used. but it has more than 30GB free.

On SQL Server we can simply " shrink file" adn it shrinks the free space.

Comment: given the freespace you have in sys and sysaux you should be adding more datafiles not resizing them.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have some tablespaces with a lot of free space. Company here is a pain in the a$$ about addind disks, so for now I would like do resize these tableSpaces to reclaim some space until we can add another disk.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for the party, but this script was gold for me at the time I found it:

```
set verify off
column file_name format a50 word_wrapped
column smallest format 999,990 heading "Smallest|Size|Poss."
column currsize format 999,990 heading "Current|Size"
column savings  format 999,990 heading "Poss.|Savings"
break on report
compute sum of savings on report
column value new_val blksize
select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_block_size';
/
select file_name,
       ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*&&blksize)/1024/1024 ) smallest,
       ceil( blocks*&&blksize/1024/1024) currsize,
       ceil( blocks*&&blksize/1024/1024) -
       ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*&&blksize)/1024/1024 ) savings
from dba_data_files a,
     ( select file_id, max(block_id+blocks-1) hwm
         from dba_extents
        group by file_id ) b
where a.file_id = b.file_id(+) order by savings desc
/
```

It will tell you smallest and current size of each datafile and it will tell you how much
storage you may gain by shrinking a datafile(s combined).

Once you find the smallest possible size of a datafile, you may simply shrink it with:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'Datafile_name_bla_bla' RESIZE 20M;
```